# Unable to extract url links in python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to print the place names (cults, bankhead) in the following link

https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN#results

I've written the following code but when I run it, it thinks for a while generates a blank output and cmd prompts me to enter again.
I've tried 2 different print statments at end, i've put a # in front of the first
Any ideas, thanks & Regards

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# connection header
header={'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Cookie':'mdtp=y4Ts2Vvql5V9MMZNjqB9T+7S/vkQKPqjHHMIq5jk0J1l5l131dU0YXsq7Rr15GDyghKHrS/qcD2vdsMCVtzKByJEDZFI+roS6tN9FN5IS70q8PkCCBjgFPDZjlR1A3H9FJ/zCWXMNJbaXqF8MgqE+nhR3/lji+eK4mm/GP9b8oxlVdupo9KN9SKanxu/JFEyNXutjyN+BsxRztNem1Z+ExSQCojyxflI/tc70+bXAu3/ppdP7fIXixfEOAWezmOh3ywchn9DV7Af8wH45t8u4+Y=; mdtpdi=mdtpdi#f523cd04-e09e-48bc-9977-73f974d50cea#1484041095424_zXDAuNhEkKdpRUsfXt+/1g==; seen_cookie_message=yes; _ga=GA1.4.666959744.1484041122; _gat=1',
'Host':'https://www.saa.gov.uk/',
'Referer':'https://www.saa.gov.uk/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.51 Safari/537.36'
}

session = requests.session()

user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN#results'



response = session.get(url, headers=header)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    #print link.get('href')
    print link.find('a')['href']
```

Comment: Why are you calling link.find('a') again? haven't you already found all of the anchor elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard limit on this web page, so a simple `requests.get` would do the scraping job, as for `BeautifulSoup` part, the place names and links you are looking for are in `td` tags with no extra attribute, so [**`CSS selector`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) would be more fit for parsing.

So in this case:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN#results'
baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

response = requests.get(url)
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

for link in html.select('td a'):
    print link.text, baseurl + link['href']
```

And results:

```
...
...
BOYD ORR CLOSE https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOYD+ORR+CLOSE%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN&DD_STREET=BOYD+ORR+CLOSE#results
DON TERRACE https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=DON+TERRACE%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN&DD_STREET=DON+TERRACE#results
BYRON CRESCENT https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BYRON+CRESCENT%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN&DD_STREET=BYRON+CRESCENT#results
MARINE TERRACE https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&x=0&y=0&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=aberdeen&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=MARINE+TERRACE%2C+ABERDEEN%2C+Aberdeen+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Aberdeen+City&DD_TOWN=ABERDEEN&DD_STREET=MARINE+TERRACE#results
...
...
```

**Edit:**

If you only need to find all links in first table, all you need to do is to locate the first table first with `first_table = html.find('table')`, then search for links in this table.

```
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

first_table = html.find('table')

for link in first_table.select('td a'):
    print link.text, baseurl + link['href']
```

Comment: Many thanks Shane, is there a line i could put between the for and that would print only the results for the first localities table. Its  in html as <th scope="col">Please select one of the following <a name='results'>Localities</span>:</th>. I tried lline of code if link.find("th a", {"name":"results"}) but I'm getting a syntax error pointing to the 2nd bracket.

Comment: @OdhranHennessy: Check my edit, basically you only need to locate the first table with `first_table = html.find('table')`